# How do I trigger a CSS class state through a URL parameter?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

On our college website we have subject area pages - say, Business and Enterprise:

https://www.blackpool.ac.uk/business

This shows a list of courses.

There is a manual filter on that page so the user can choose which kind of course they want (Adult, Degree, Apprenticeship, etc).

We just introduced a megamenu for the different kinds of course (Adult, Degree, etc). But currently and irrespective of how the user lands on a subject area course page, no filter is selected.

So if you were on the Adult section of the megamenu, and clicked Business and Enterprise, you'd see the page above with none of the filters selected. Which is bad.

To select a filter, the class .course-filter .selected is called:

Degrees

So my question is what do I need to do to call the subject area page with one the filters already active - so someone expecting all the Adult courses in Business and Enterprise would see only them at https://www.blackpool.ac.uk/business ?

Many thanks for all your help!

Comment: You can store all checked filter in `local-storage` or `cookie` on **checkbox** change event so next time your page is going to refresh then you will get that filter from local storage and retrieve all the selected filter in new page

Comment: try using jquery cookies, and store the currently selected filter. then when a new page loads, first check for the cookie. if its empty load without filter if it cointains a filter, load that filter

Comment: on this link https://www.blackpool.ac.uk/engineering you can get all selected filter using this 
`console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("course-filter selected"))` please check in console

Comment: Oh my goodness! Thanks so much for these insights - super appreciated.

But I'll be honest - I'm still no clearer as to how I could invoke the filter being automatically selected when a user enters that page based on the previous page.

For example, how someone clicking Business and Enterprise in the Adult section of the megamenu would see the course list with the Adult filter already active.

Thanks much!